# Why do I get a msg that an error occurred on a certain character in a file, when the entire file apparently does not contain that many characters?

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control, outofrangeexception

When I assign an html file to a WebBrowser's Url property, I get this Script err:

[image]

So, in an effort to determine what is causing the mayhem, I changed the extension of the file from .html to .txt and tried this code, starting from a spot just before what was flagged as bad:

```
int dangerZone = 95217560;
string path = @"C:\misc\mapcode_20160720_022208.txt"; 
string readText = File.ReadAllText(path);
string stuffNearAndPastTheProblem = readText.Substring(dangerZone);
MessageBox.Show(stuffNearAndPastTheProblem);
```

...but, instead of being enlightened with whatever html is malformed or otherwise problematic, I get a crash that tells me:

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled   HResult=-2146233086
>   Message=startIndex cannot be larger than length of string.

How can there be a problem at character 95217563 when there are not even 95217560 characters in the file?

### UPDATE

Okay, I tried this to check the length:

```
var chars = readText.ToCharArray();
MessageBox.Show(chars.Length.ToString());
```

...and it tells me 24131.

So the char position from the err msg is, indeed, the epitome of bogusness.

### UPDATE 2

So I changed the "dangerZone" value to 2100, and the MessageBox displayed is bigger than King Kong on steroids. So obviously there are *a lot* more than 24131 chars...

Maybe what's happening is that these lines in the .html/.txt file:

```
sb.Append("<script src=\"http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js\"></script> ");
sb.Append("<script src=\"http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false\"></script> ");
sb.Append("<script src=\"gomap.js\"></script> ");
sb.Append("<!--[if IE]>");
sb.Append("<script src=\"http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js\"></script>");
sb.Append("<![endif]-->");
```

...are including those referenced .js files in the err msg's character locating calculations. IOW, it may be inserting those referenced files "inline" like so:

```
part of my file
jquery.min.js
google maps api js
gomap.js
html5.js
...and then back to the rest of my file
```

...and then basing the problematic char location on all of that combined html and js, whereas only a relatively small subset is actually contained in the .text file.

If my hunch about the frankensteinization of the script's "working set" is correct, then yes, the "bad char" location provided in the Script err msg is pretty much useless (in my case, anyway).

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't that be cause `readText.Substring(dangerZone)` would be substituted with `readText.Substring(95217560)` which means you are specifying `95217560` as the start index of the substring operation. Do your file really have that length of characters?

You are using overload [`String.Substring Method (Int32)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hxthx5h6(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
public string Substring(
    int startIndex
)
```

what number in error message `HResult=-2146233086`??? You are wrong. See MSDN [`ArgumentOutOfRangeException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentoutofrangeexception(v=vs.110).aspx) and as it says:

> HResult    Gets or sets HRESULT, a coded numerical value that is
>   assigned to a specific exception.(Inherited from Exception.)

That's not related to the number of characters in your file content.

Comment: That's my point - doesn't the err msg indicate there *are* at least that many chars?

Comment: @B.ClayShannon, NO, the exception rather says *there aren't that many characters* else that exception would never occur.

Comment: So the number in the err msg is completely bogus? If so, what value is it?

Comment: I'm not talking about that number, I'm talking about "Char: 95217563"

Comment: @B.ClayShannon, not pretty sure but that's surely doesn't reference no.of characters. Can you provide bit more information about that script file

Comment: What else would it signify but the char at which the problem was encountered? I could try to post the entire file, but it might be too large for the StackOverflow limitation on post size.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon, doesn't make sense posting entire HTML ... I now see what your actual question is. That's really strange and yes that says at which characterline the error is